# Fseek rolls back 8 byte,but I want it to be 4 bytes

Tags: c, file, fseek

```
for (int i = 0; i < num - 1 - ct; i++) {
    int tmp = k;
    fread(&k, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fflush(stdin);
    fseek(fp, -(sizeof(int)), SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
}
```

The question part is above.
I want `fseek` to roll back 4 bytes every time. But it rolls back 8 bytes or maybe roll back to the beginning of the file. I can't make it work right. A freshman. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Belaying the pointlessness and undefined-behavior nature of  fflush of `stdin`, have you actually verified *any* of your IO calls by checking their result codes? They're not just there for convenience; they're there to help you trace down potential problems.

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` invokes UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/995714)

Comment: You don't show where `k` is defined or how it is initialized before the loop.  How have you determined that `fseek()` reverses by 8 bytes instead of 4?  Have you checked that `fp` is valid?  How is it opened?  Did you use `"rb+"` mode?  However, the major problem may be the absence of an `fseek()` between the `fwrite()` at the end of one iteration of the loop and the `fread()` at the beginning of the next.  You have to do an `fseek()` when switching from reading to writing (and you do) and also when switching from writing to reading (which you don't do).  That leads to undefined behaviour, UB.

Comment: You `fflush(stdin)` and read/seek/write `fp`. Is it what you want?

Comment: the expression: `sizeof( int )`  will return 8 if the underlying hardware is 64 bit, the same as it returns 4 if the underlying hardware is 32 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you do not use `fseek()` to sync the stream's internal data when switching from writing to reading from the same stream.

Try this:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
for (int i = 0; i < num - 1 - ct; i++) {
    int tmp = k;
    fread(&k, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    //fflush(stdin);  // this has undefined behavior
    fseek(fp, -(sizeof(int)), SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try saving current position before reading and the use that position to move the file pointer. Be sure to open the file is "r+b" mode.

```
fp = fopen("Your file name", "r+b");
....
for (int i = 0; i < num - 1 - ct; i++){
    int tmp = k;
    long pos = ftell(fp);
    fread(&k, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fflush(stdin);   // What has stdin to do here while your read/seek/write fp
    fseek(fp, pos - sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&tmp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
}
```

And don't forget to add checking the return value of *any* of the function used.

Comment: Or use [`fgetpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetpos) and [`fsetpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fsetpos)